# Eventhandler for UserControl with button onClick event

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, event-handling

I've created a user control that contains a button and a few other controls.

When declaring my user control in the html markup I'd like to do some sort of :

```
<asp:CustomControl onclick="CustomControl_Click" ID="cc1" runat="server">
```

Where CustomControl_Click is obviously the action I want to call when my control's button is clicked.

So far in my control I have:

```
public event EventHandler Click;

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Click.Invoke(sender, e);
    }
```

but how can I *forward* the Eventhandler of the parent page to assign it to the Click Eventhandler in my control?

Any help is **really** appreciated!

PS: maybe there's a way of getting the method from the hosting page using reflexion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm using a custom button (actually html div with **LinkButton** embedded in it). Here is code of it:

```
    public delegate void ClickEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
    public event ClickEventHandler Click =  delegate { };

    public string Text
    {
        get { return cmdLink.Text; }
        set { cmdLink.Text = value; }
    }

    public bool CausesValidation
    {
        get { return cmdLink.CausesValidation; }
        set { cmdLink.CausesValidation = value; }
    }

    public string OnClientClick
    {
        get { return cmdLink.OnClientClick; }
        set { cmdLink.OnClientClick = value; }
    }

    public string CssClass
    {
        get { return cmdLink.CssClass; }
        set { cmdLink.CssClass = value; }
    }

    protected void cmdLink_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Click(this, e);
    }
```

Here is usage in aspx page:

```
<Button_Control:ButtonControl ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" 
          OnClick="btnSaveClick" />
```

and this is in code-behind page of aspx page:

```
    protected void btnSaveClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //do stuff here
    }
```

Comment: But Still how do you map "OnClick="btnSaveClick" to the ClickEventHandler Click ??

Comment: I guess it's a convention then?

Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: You have to write OnClick="btnSaveClick" and write event handler method in your code behind page. It is called by control's Click event.

Comment: I'd be better to remove " = delegate { }", so you can do "Click != null" to check if the event was assigned

Answer (score 0):

I found it!

Instead of using event bubbling I use reflexion in the click eventhandler of the user control so I have :

```
public string OnClick;

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MethodInfo methodInfo = this.Page.GetType().GetMethod(OnClick);
        methodInfo.Invoke(this.Page, new object[]{ sender, e });
    }
```

And it works with declaring the user control as :

```
<asp:CustomControl OnClick="CustomControl_Click" ID="cc1" runat="server">
```

Comment: It is reflection not reflexion and delegates and event handlers just do that for you automatically!